# Sony Smart Eye Glass can't activate High Power Mode

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I'm using below API

```
utils.setPowerMode(Intents.POWER_MODE_HIGH);
```

I usually can't activate High Power Mode of Sony Smart Eye Glass even try on built-in camera app of the Glass.
I tried with many Android devices to connect to my Glass such as: SamSung S7/S4, Google Nexus 5x, Sony Z2 but the result is the same.
I tried to reset factory the Glass and the result is the same.
Is my Glass broken?
Is it due to my Android device or the Glass I'm using? Is it hardware issue?
Appreciate any help :">

Comment: Does it ever work at all or only intermittently?

Comment: After reboot/reset factory the Glass, it can work for the first time. Then after using awhile, it become hard to switch to high power mode again. After this happens, I almost can't switch to high power mode

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug and there isn't a workaround available at this time.  You can check our SmartEyeglass developer page for updates in the future https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/.